# How to encourage players to fight nearby players instead of clustering into mega-factions?

Tags: game-design, game-mechanics, balance

My game is a location-based RTS game with roughly 150 players on 5 continents. Players can create and join alliances essentially at whim, and the players use discord for communication.

There is a dilemma, though: at present, all players in the USA are allied, and all players outside the USA are allied. The players inside the USA typically ally only when there is a threat, other than that they are constantly infighting, which is good.

However, players outside the US want to be allies and resist fighting eachother under any circumstance. They also actively work to stifle combat globally to maintain "peace."

My question is, how can I get them to fight eachother? This is only a problem when the non-US players have the majority of the power, because when the US players have the power, they infight constantly. I can't just limit the size of alliances, because the non-US players will simply break into many smaller alliances but will still fly the same flag.

Some ideas I have considered:

- Give players random targets to kill. If they kill the target/destroy the target's structures, they get extra reward.
- Remove the ability to create and join alliances, instead have several pre-determined factions players are placed into depending on geographic location. (Or on some other factor, or randomize it altogether.) Players could still jockey to be the leader of their faction.

I would appreciate any input you guys might have and I am happy to provide more information as necessary.

Comment: The question is: Why is there a large amount of players who want to "maintain peace"? What motivates them? Is "peace" gameplay perhaps more rewarding than "war" gameplay? And is that necessarily bad?

Comment: Frame Challenge: are your players having fun? Do the non-US players report that they don't have fun because there is no fighting?From what you describe

Answer (score 0):

One idea you could consider is implementing a mechanic that encourages players to compete for resources. If non-US players are able to maintain peace and work together, they may have an advantage in terms of resource acquisition and management. By introducing competition for resources, you may be able to encourage players to engage in conflict with one another.

Another option you could consider is implementing a ranking or leaderboard system that rewards players for attacking and defeating other players. This could incentivize players to engage in combat in order to climb the leaderboard and earn rewards.

You could also consider introducing events or challenges that require players to work against one another in order to complete them. This could provide a temporary reason for players to engage in conflict and give them a chance to compete against one another.

Ultimately, the solution will depend on the specific mechanics and dynamics of your game. You may want to consider collecting feedback from your players and experimenting with different approaches to see what works best in your specific game.